# How to progressively manipulate equations using beamer

Tags: beamer, equations, overlays, uncover, only

Say I have an equation and want to show some algebraic steps before getting to the solution. Is there a way to replace the newly processed equation at each frame, instead of uncovering many subsequent steps?

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{flalign*}
\uncover<1->{
-3\pi\eta r\dv{\langle x^2\rangle}{t}+\langle\xi(t)x\rangle&=\frac{1}{2}m\dv[2]{\langle x^2\rangle}{t}-\langle mv^2\rangle&&\\}
\uncover<2->
{-3\pi\eta r\dv{\langle x^2\rangle}{t}+\langle\xi(t)x\rangle&=\frac{1}{2}m\dv[2]{\langle x^2\rangle}{t}-\cancelto{k_BT}{\langle mv^2\rangle&&\\}
\end{flalign*}

\end{frame}
```

Comment: Please get into the habit of adding a short, but compilable text document to your questions.

Comment: Your code fragment does not compile. The necessary packages and document structure to compile it is missing and there is a missing `}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the `\cancelto` macro overlay aware, this way you could simply use it like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{physics}

\renewcommand<>{\cancelto}[2]{\rule{0pt}{1.5\baselineskip}\alt#3{\beameroriginal{\cancelto}{#1}{#2}}{#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{flalign*}
-3\pi\eta r\dv{\langle x^2\rangle}{t}+\langle\xi(t)x\rangle&=\frac{1}{2}m\dv[2]{\langle x^2\rangle}{t}-\cancelto<2>{k_BT}{\langle mv^2\rangle}&&
\end{flalign*}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]